# xsl grouping two different attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure:

```
<table>
  <field1>User 1</field1>
  <field2>xyz</field2>
  <field3>xyz</field3>
</table>
<table>
  <field1>User 2</field1>
  <field2>abc</field2>
  <field3>xyz</field3>
</table>
<table>
  <field1>User 3</field1>
  <field2>def</field2>
  <field3>xyz</field3>
</table>
<table>
  <field1>User 2</field1>
  <field2>def</field2>
  <field3>xyz</field3>
</table>
```

The XML has several 100 table entries.
The attributes could be within field 2 or field 3 or in both.

I need an Output, which is grouping the users and also the attributes from the fields 2 and 3 in a table.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>Users</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>User 2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>User 3</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

In a second step I have to Count the values but this is an other topic.

I can only use XSLT 1.0 and unfortunately I have no idea how I can group the values from the fields 2 and 3?

Many thanks in advance for your Support!

Comment: Please edit your code sample so that it is well-formed XML, currently it is not clear which name and values your attributes have.

Comment: I agree with @MartinHonnen. Most importantly: do the fields have different names?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I pastet here a very simple translation of the original XML source. The main point is, as @michael.hor257k ask, the fields have different names in the XML source. Thats the reason why I have problems to group "field 2 and field 3". Many thanks and best regards, Claus

Comment: Please  post a **representative** and **well-formed** example of your input. If the fields have different names, why doesn't your example show that?

Comment: Sorry, I named them now field1, field2, field3... I hope the difference is now better visible? BR

Comment: Don't you understand what well-formed means? For example, `<field1>User 1</field>` is not well-formed because the closing tag does not match the opening tag. And `<table>` does not match `<tables>`. And `<tables>` is not a closing tag. And ...

Comment: Sorry again, I lose sight of the not matching closing tags/names of the XML example. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had a **well-formed input** such as this:

```
<input>
    <object>
        <name>User 1</name>
        <color1>Red</color1>
        <color2>Red</color2>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>User 2</name>
        <color1>Green</color1>
        <color2>Red</color2>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>User 3</name>
        <color1>Blue</color1>
        <color2>Red</color2>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>User 2</name>
        <color1>Blue</color1>
        <color2>Red</color2>
    </object>
</input>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="object" match="object" use="name" />
<xsl:key name="color" match="color1 | color2" use="." />
<xsl:key name="color-by-object" match="color1 | color2" use="concat(../name, '|', .)" />

<xsl:variable name="columns">
    <xsl:for-each select="(input/object/color1 | input/object/color2)[count(. | key('color', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <color><xsl:value-of select="."/></color>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="col-set" select="exsl:node-set($columns)" />

<xsl:variable name="rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="input/object[count(. | key('object', name)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="row-set" select="exsl:node-set($rows)" />

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col-set/color">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$row-set/name">
            <xsl:variable name="object" select="." />
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="$object"/></th>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-set/color">
                    <xsl:variable name="color" select="." />
                    <!-- switch to document in order to use key -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$root">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('color-by-object', concat($object, '|', $color)))"/></td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would **result** in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th/>
      <th>Red</th>
      <th>Green</th>
      <th>Blue</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>User 1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>User 2</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>User 3</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your support @michael.hor257k! I will try this suggestion and give you feedback. BR

Comment: As you wrote @Michael.hor257k the proposed solution is exactly doing what I Need!

Comment: But unfortunately I don't understand why the concat of "name" is needed at the key?

Comment: Because each cell of the table needs to count (all and only) values that match **both** the current cell's name (horizontal) and color (vertical).

Comment: Mabey I'm blind, but I didn't find the Option to accept the answer?
In additional to your solution there are new questions from my site. Am I right, if I need a sum per row and sum per colum, I can solve this by specific keys and counting them in a smiliar way as in your proposal? Many thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for all your support! I will try to solve this question by myself first. :-) BR